# Is there another way to put raster into PostGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

Is there another way to put raster into PostGIS?
I have tried with raster2pgsql.exe but it does not recognize **raste2pgsql**.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that storing images/rasters in a PostgreSQL-db is the most efficient way to store them. Usually PostgreSQL are used for vectors. You might have more potency by storing it as GeoTIFF in a OS-folder system.

Comment: First problem is the blank in "GIS Database" (you have to quote the path). Besides you have to set more parameter and you have to pipe the result to your database (paramter: host, port, user, etc.). See the docs: http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/using_raster_dataman.html

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain error messages as **text**. This makes your content more readable on all devices, and anyone else with the same question could locate your answer with a text search. As a new user, please take the [tour]

Answer (score 3):

It's a case of space in your path... try to wrap it into " " or place file in some path without spaces in names